# Compiler outputting IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

```
ArrayList beds = new ArrayList(49);
public Patient getPatient(int bedNumber) {
    if (beds.get(bedNumber) != null) {
        return (Patient) beds.get(bedNumber);
    } 
    else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

I'm having a problem where I can't seem to get Java to output null in a method.

Say I assign a patient to an item in the beds ArrayList, then try to get the patient at the 11th bed using the getPatient method created above, however you can't as 11 patients haven't been added. How can I make it output null when I try to do this instead of java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Just to check: What do you think `new ArrayList(49)` does?

Comment: Also, why aren't you using `ArrayList<Patient>`?

Comment: The compiler doesn't output IndexOutOfBoundsException (unless it's seriously broken).

Comment: @immibis creates an ArrayList with a fixed capacity of 50? Spec.

Comment: @HotLicks The JVM, the output on the console, whatever you want to call it.

Comment: What you're saying is you get an exception when you run the code.  This is different from getting a compiler error.

Comment: @user2177940 Not quite. What do you think will happen when you try to add 51 elements?

Answer (score 1):

First off, the compiler has nothing to do with this as it's the JVM that's showing the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

What you should do is check your bedNumber against the size of the ArrayList, not whether the ArrayList item that doesn't exist (is out of bounds) is null. So do simple int math.

i.e.,

```
if (bedNumber > 0 && bedNumber < beds.size()) {
    // do your stuff here
} else {
    // myself, I'd throw an exception here, not return null
}
```

Comment: Yes I know I should be doing this but it's not what I'm supposed to be doing, what I'm supposed to be doing is outputting null when there is no 11th patient.

Comment: @user2177940: then return null.

Answer (score 1):

You can just modify the `if` statement to check the size of the `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList beds = new ArrayList(49);
public Patient getPatient(int bedNumber) {
    if (bedNumber < beds.size()) {
        return (Patient) beds.get(bedNumber);
    } 
    else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: So what about when there's elements in 12 and 13 but not in 11?

Comment: If there is an empty space, it will have the value of `null`. The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` comes from when you are accessing outside of the `ArrayList`, not when you are accessing an empty space.

Comment: But I've defined the ArrayList capacity as 50, so there's 50 initial empty spaces?

Comment: You initially define the capacity as 49, so they will be 49 empty spaces.

Answer (score 0):

While the advice in the other answers is pretty good, one thing that's overlooked is the constructor on your [raw] `ArrayList`.

`new ArrayList(49)` will only [set the initial capacity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int)) of your `ArrayList` before it has to resize.  That doesn't impact how *large* the array list is at all; if you haven't added any elements into it, its size will still report `0`.

Check your bounds; if they enter in a value that's larger than what you support, then reject it.

```
// The zeroth location in a list is the first element in it.
if(0 <= bedNumber && bedNumber < beds.size()) {
    // Cast necessary since it's a raw ArrayList
    // Totally avoidable if you use ArrayList<Patient>
    return (Patient) beds.get(bedNumber);
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: How do I set a size then?

Comment: Add things.  The only size that matters in a `List` of any kind is how many things the list supports.

Answer (score 0):

The point here is that your beds List actually has size of zero. So beds.get(i) whatever the i be would throw that exception as it should. I think you are mistaking the way we define array in Java with defining an ArrayList